# taskbar group menus no longer retain desired sorting order

Tags: taskbar, sorting

On my taskbar in Windows 10 I have several toolbar groups. For example "multimedia", "drives", "imaging apps"etc.
I have for the toolbar groups only the "show title" turned on and the tool groups (folders) tightly together. When I click on the little double arrow >> I get a vertical menu showing whatever the folder contains; files, folders, shortcuts etc.

It used to be that I could arranging the order of the menu and it would retain it.
Now suddenly it does not save it anymore and next time I reboot it has rearranged itself again to some sort of default order. So far I have been unable to find an answer on the Internet or in the GPedit.

Locking the taskbar makes no difference and looks worse because a sliver of the icons show.

On my recently purchased laptop this works. I spent some time comparing registry entries that I would think are relevant but could not find any difference. recently however, some toolbar groups but not all on the laptop start to show the same behavior.

So far I have not found anybody knowledgeable as to what the problem is and how to correct it and/or registry entry to change. Anybody out here?

Comment: Which OS is it, Windows 10?

Comment: Windows 10 1803, 1809 &  1903

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]** Taskbar Toolgroups used to retain menu order

By accident and a slip of the hand I found the solution!
Forget the registry, you going to die before you find an answer.

I was moving a shortcut on my desktop to a lower region when I slipped off the mouse pad with the mouse.
The mouse pointer was over the double arrow (Chevron) of one of the tool groups in the taskbar. A text popped up with a right pointing arrow and the word "move to" resp. "move to 'xyz' [group]".
It was at that moment I had let go of the left mouse button.
The shortcut was now in the pop-up menu of that taskbar toolbar group but also still remained on the desktop. It was not actually "moved" as indicated. the shortcut item name started with an X and was in the very top of the menu before any alphanumerical entries or folders and links.

A few days later I rebooted the system and had forgotten about it. But when I later clicked on that particular taskbar toolbar group I noticed that that accidentally moved link was still in the same position in the menu. this indicated to me that it retained the custom desired order. so I rearranged in that particular pop-up menu several items and rebooted.
Lo and behold! the menu retained the order I had sorted it in since my problem was that all menus suddenly sorted automatically by name and not by custom arrangement!

So I did a test with all the other menus by dragging one random shortcut into each menu and rearranged the menu order, rebooted and, hooray! all the menus now retained the desired sorting order again!
Removing that particular previously dragged in shortcut thereafter did not have an adverse effect either.

Trying to find out the before-and-after difference in the registry has so far been a quest equal to finding the Oak Island treasure... all sorts of irrelevant entries with lengthy cryptic hexadecimal entries but nothing that would indicate were the culprit and answer to the solution lies.

Important to note is however, that this does not work if you right click and open that particular taskbar toolbar group folder and drag an item into. the restoration of the custom sort order only works when you drag any given shortcut from the desktop over the double arrow Chevron. you can thereafter delete that previously tracked shortcut.  the sort order will be retained.

I hope this helps all who have dealt with that issue!

Comment: Dorcom, you saved my day! I had the same issue: my custom order disappeared one day, I don't know exactly when and how, but I hadn't found any solution until I read your thread. And it worked at first try. I applied it to two impacted systems with success. Thanks a lot, that did the trick.

Comment: OK, but I also did confirm that this trick was applicable to my situation for two different laptops, confirming that it is not restricted to a specific context.

Comment: Thank you and I'm happy I could help!